# What is pokemon-like game's view called?

Tags: 2d, camera

I'm trying to make a game with a top down view, but angled, like pokemon, zenonia, zelda(I think), and most rpgs(specially the ones made with rpg maker).
But I don't know what is this view called so I'm finding it tricky to get resources or even assets. I heard things like bird-view, 3/4. But I don't really know the exact name. 
I would also apreciate any resources or guide with this type of games.

Thanks!

Comment: I only call it top-down

Comment: but top down is a little bit ambiguous, I mean, I say some game is a top down, how can you tell it has this "angled" look or a straight top down view like cs2d or gta2?

Comment: Think your talking about top down isometric perspective.